# vector space dimension of linear varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-geometry

Suppose $Y=Z(f_1,\cdots ,f_r)\subseteq \mathbb{A}^n_k$ where each $f_i$'s are linear homogeneous polynomials which are $k$-linear independent. Then $Y$ is also a vector space over $k$. My question: Is the vector space dimension of $Y$ is same as the dimension of $Y$ as an affine variety? If yes how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Note that $Y$ is given as $Ax=0$, where $A$ is a $n \times r$-matrix containing the coefficients of the $f_i$.

Thus $Y= \ker A$.

This should now be clear, maybe depending upon your definition of "dimension".

**EDIT** Now that we have a definition of dimension to work with: we can at least immediately bound the dimension: any linear subspace has a filtration $0 \subset V_1 \subset V_2 \subset \ldots \subset Y$. Here $0$ is a point, $V_1$ is a line, $V_2$ is a plane and so on. Then the Zariski dimension must be greater than or equal to $\dim \ker A$.

Too see that we must equality, suppose that we could fit an irreducible algebraic subset inbetween $V_k$ and $V_{k+1}$. Without loss of generality, we could assume that $V_k$ is defined by $x_0=x_1=\ldots=x_{n-k}=0$, and $V_{k+1}$ is defined similarly (with one condition less).

If $V$ is an irreducible algebraic subset such that $V_k \subset V \subset V_{k+1}$, then $V$ must be defind by some ideal $I_V$ such that $I_{V_{k+1}} \subset I_V \subset I_{V_k}$. But this means that $I_V$ is  stricly contained in and non-zero in $I_{V_k}/I_{V_{k+1}} = (\overline{x_{n_k}}) \simeq k$. But this is impossible, since the latter is a 1-dimensional vector space.

Comment: I am sorry but it is not clear. What do you mean by "$Y=\ker A$"? The definition of dimension in a space with Zariski topology $X$ is $\max \{t| Z_0\subset Z_1\subset\cdots ,\subset Z_t\}$ where $Z_i$'s are irreducible closed subset of $X$ and the containments are proper.

Comment: @2015 Does this clarify?

Comment: @ Fredrik Meyer Your explanation is useful. But I think I found another way to explain it: The vector space dimension of the zero set = Nulity of the matrix A ($\dim\ker A$)= $n-r$ ($r$-the number of linear independent linear polynomials which generate the ideal here)(using the rank nulity theorem in linear algebra)= Zariski dimension of the space. Is this explanation correct? Please let me know.

Comment: @2015 Yes, Zariski dimension is the same as vector space dimension. So you can say it follows from the rank nullity theorem, yes.